# My nobles won't support a law

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm trying to increase the level of tax on cities.  Currently no-one is voting for it except me (3/11 votes).  I've looked through this site, and found comments to the effect of 'Your vassals don't like you enough!  Get more popular with them!'

That hasn't worked for me.  Currently I have three vassals.  One has an opinion of me of +87.  The other two both have an opinion of me of +100.  None of them are voting in favor of this law change (see the screenshot attached).  What can I do to get it passed, if +100 opinion is not enough?

[image: Here's a screenshot from my game]

Comment: How much time has passed in game? Nobles won't necessarily cast their vote immediately.

Comment: I had the [same problem](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/220877/68226). Took a few months of game time for the votes to roll in. There doesn't seem to be any penalty for leaving the vote open for an extended period of time, so yeah, what @DMK said: how long have you waited?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that giving them a cash gift will almost always get them to change their vote, assuming their opinion of you is positive afterwards. The mild opinion boosts from honorary titles don't seem to cut it.